# How to use useNavigation() within @react-navigation drawer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-context

**Current Behavior**

I have a react-native application that use [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) v5 for the routing.

1. I have a drawer (offeset menu left) in all my views
2. I use the stackNavigation for page transition.

Because of *(1)*, my structure is `drawerNavigator (a) > stackNavigator (b) > views (c)`.

When I try to call the `useNavigation()` hook within my `<DrawerContent />`, I have the following error:

```
Error: We couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a navigator?
    at useNavigation (bundle.js:8766)
```

Yes, I am not inside the `stackNavigator` so the hook cannot be called

**Expected Behavior**

I expect to have navigation available within my `<DrawerContent />`.

**Your Environment**

```
| software                       | version |
| ------------------------------ | ------- |
| iOS or Android                 | iOS, Android and web
| @react-navigation/native       | 5.0.0-alpha.41
| @react-navigation/stack         | 5.0.0-alpha.63
| @react-navigation/drawer       | 5.0.0-alpha.41
| react-native-reanimated        | 1.4.0
| react-native-gesture-handler   | 1.5.3
| react-native-safe-area-context | 0.6.2
| react-native-screens           | 2.0.0-alpha.32
| react-native                   | https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz
| expo                           | SDK36
| node                           | v13.5.0
| npm or yarn                    | 6.13.7
```

How can I use [`@react-navigation/stack`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/packages/stack) inside [`@react-navigation/drawer`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/packages/drawer) or how should I build my drawer and app with them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Create `RootNavigation` :

```
import { createRef } from 'react';

export const navigationRef = createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

export function goBack() {
  navigationRef.current?.goBack();
}
```

In `App.js`:

```
import { navigationRef } from './navigation/RootNavigation';
// ...
<NavigationContainer
  ref={navigationRef}
>
  {children}
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then import `RootNavigation` from any source and you will not have to worry about the react tree.

Comment: Anyway, can't reach `closeDrawer` function. For me, this example is working: https://rb.gy/ra0irs

Comment: This also brings a lot of problems (missing function, bad current route, etc...), be aware that I have not found a good and valid solution that restore all the features.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using React Navigation 5x, I followed this guide and still succeed using first approach (for old RNavigation).
Details: mock the `useNavigation` function

```
jest.mock(‘react-navigation-hooks’, () => ({
 useNavigation: () => jest.fn(),
 useNavigationParam: jest.fn(jest.requireActual(
  'react-navigation-hooks'
 ).useNavigationParam),
}));
```

Comment: How will i implement this function in my testing component. Can you give me an example with V5?.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `useNavigation` if you're on a screen in the Navigator.

The structure of the navigator is as follows.

- stackNavigator

  - drawerNavigator

    - drawerScreens
- stackScreens

The screen movement is as follows.

**Example**

```js
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('moveScreenName')}
        title="Go to moveScreenName"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

`useNavigation` is a hook which gives access to `navigation` object. It's useful when you cannot pass the `navigation` prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

`useNavigation()` returns the navigation prop of the screen it's inside.

**Example**

```js
function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I am **not on a screen** in the navigator, I am **within the `DrawerContent`**. Also, my structure is `drawerNavigator` **wrapping** `stackNavigator`, do you suggest to do the opposit? If I did that, it's only **because I want one drawer for all my app and not one per stack views**

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa  What you're trying to do now is put all the stacks in one drawer. The same is the way I do it. The structure is at one's disposal. But to do the way you want, my answer is well structured.

Comment: I have tried to use the layout you recommended but unfortunately, I have this error: `A navigator can only contain 'Screen' components as its direct children (found `DrawerNavigator`)`. Do you have an example of implementation if you have tried to make one?

Comment: Except your file structure which tell that  `stackScreens` brother of `stackNavigator` which is literally impossible, the rest is not related to my question. I am curious to see a working example of how you would create the drawer in a different scenario than mine without creating multiple drawers for each pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this video in here - https://youtu.be/hLP1G29bbLU

You can see the usage of
`useNavigation hook` in the video.